# Python Request Issue - POST

Tags: python, json, http, post

I am attempting to sending JSON data to url server i.e. ("https://exampleurl.com/example?data=") and for some reason I am getting a 400 status code. Is there something wrong I am doing?

```
import requests

payload = {
"name":"Jane Doe"
}

r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/example?data=', json=payload)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Your program works perfectly for me after changing the URL to a real one: `https://httpbin.org/post?data=`. Perhaps you should look at your server?

Comment: Do you mean by using a get method? @Robᵩ

Answer (score 0):

It looks basically okay, but I think you should apply good format for your json file.
Please add proper indentation and put a space between ":" and "Jane Doe".
And sometimes some post needs you to add headers for checking content type or password for using "POST", especially when they need to check you are authorized user. For more info, I think you need to check the official doc of the URL.

```
import requests

payload = {
    "name": "Jane Doe"
}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/example?data=', headers=headers, json=payload)

print(r.text)
```

If this solution doesn't work, you should consider these factors:

1. Is your URL correct?
2. Is your request open for HTTPS protocol?
3. Do you need to apply some proxy for your development environment?

Hope this help you:)

Comment: @beloas thank you for your comment here.
If what you said is correct, I think that URL requires you to have some headers for valid requests. Please check the doc of the website and try adding "headers." I changed my answer contents.

Comment: I honestly have no clue what is wrong with the URL but it still returns a status code of 400 and says No data passed after attempting to add "headers".

Answer (score 0):

you can try **params**

```
payload = {"name":"Jane Doe"}


r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/example', params=payload)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be set to json instead of params? However even with this attempt I still receive a status code of 400. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of json=payload, do this:

```
import requests
import json

payload = {
"name":"Jane Doe"
}

r = requests.post('https://exampleurl.com/example?data=', data=json.dumps(payload))

print(r.text)
```

Comment: I apologize I attempted this prior to your post, however I still am receiving a status code of 400 with this. Don't understand why.